# processing multiple ResultSet

Tags: java

I have the below class with 3 resultsets.

```
public class AllMetricsResultSet {

        ResultSet top10Files;
        ResultSet top10FilesForUsage;
        ResultSet top10DataSet;

    }
```

In another method, I have 3 different select statements(I've given only one select below, but there are 3) which assign result sets into the above.

```
public AllMetricsResultSet SPDataList (String alldata)
{
...........

     String sSQL = "SELECT USERNAME, NUMBEROFFILES FROM FILE_INFO";

     PreparedStatement stm = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sSQL);

                    if (stm.execute())
                        //TopTenantsForUsage = stm.getResultSet();
                        rs.top10Files = stm.getResultSet();
                        rs.top10FilesForUsage = stm.getResultSet();
                        rs.top10DataSet = stm.getResultSet()
```

Then finally from another method, I am calling the previous method as follows:

```
AllMetricsResultSet mrs = SPDataList(alldata);

        while (mrs.top10Files.next())
```

(This while statement fails. I see that there are 10 rows returned. I tried `mrs.top10Files.getFetchSize()` (this also failed)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you close the Statement or Connection?

Comment: print your error stack .

Comment: I do have stm.close(); after every select. I see that all the three result sets have 10rows returned. But the while fails. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to execute the queries in one method and read data from the result sets in a different method.

You want to finish your DB access as quick as possible and close the connection,  in order to return the connection to the connection pool (relevant when you have multiple threads accessing the db) and release any db locks your statements may require.

Therefore the result set variables shouldn't br instance variables at all. You should create and consume them in the same method.

You could have, though,  a separate method for each of your 3 queries, and each of them can return the data it fetched.

Comment: I created a new method for one of the selects. It returns a ResultSet. I did a while on the rs it returned. Again it fails on the while.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try like this

```
public AllMetricsResultSet SPDataList (String alldata) {

    String sSQL1 = "query1";
    String sSQL2 = "query2";
    String sSQL3 = "query3";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stm1 = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sSQL1);
        PreparedStatement stm2 = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sSQL2);
        PreparedStatement stm3 = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sSQL3);

        if (stm1.execute())
            top10Files = stm1.getResultSet();
        if (stm2.execute())
            top10FilesForUsage = stm2.getResultSet();
        if (stm3.execute())
            top10DataSet = stm3.getResultSet();
        while (top10Files.next()) {
            //get the resultset1 data   
        }
        while (top10FilesForUsage.next()) {
            //get the resultset2 data   
        }
        while (top10DataSet.next()) {
            //get the resultset3 data   
        }
 // dont know why as you want to return the classType
 //create an object of the class initialize it the the data you obtained 
 //and return it
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        //resultsetobject close
        //statementObject close
        //connection object close
    }
}
```